# Indirect modification of overloaded property with getters and setters

Tags: php

I have a method that looks something like this:

```
public function init(){
    $this->app->classes = [
        'route'       => new Route(),
        'routeParams' => new RouteParams()
    ];

    return $this->app;
}
```

the classes property within `App` looks like this

```
class App{
    protected $classes = [];
}
```

I have another method that eventually gets called which has this line in it:

```
// Both $val and $item1 are strings
$this->app->classes['routeParams']->$val = $item1;
```

and when I run it, I get this error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property App::$classes has no effect

My `RouteParams` class looks like this:

```
class RouteParams{

    private $parameters = array();

    public function __get($name){
        if(isset($this->parameters[$name])){
            return $this->parameters[$name];
        }
        return '';
    }

    public function __set($name, $value){
        $this->parameters[$name] = $value;
    }

}
```

What is causing my error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect that: `$this->app->classes['routeParams']->$val = $item1;` should be something like 1) get the object: `$routeObject = $this->app->classes['routeParams'];` And then modify it: `$routeObject->$val = $item1;`. If that doesn't work then please create a set of compilable classes, that we can run, that demonstrates the error.

Comment: That does seem to have fixed the issue. Seems like a strange fix to me. Looking around it looks like there has been bugs submitted to fix this...

Comment: One of the many quirks of PHP? ;-/